# Using PyFacebook with the latest Django release

Tags: django, pyfacebook

The PyFacebook documentation states that

> Applications built with djangofb.py are not compatible with django 1.x. Download django-facebookconnect instead.

Is this true? Has anyone managed to work this with Django 1.2.1?

Answer (score 0):

It is, use django-facebookconnect.